# Error: The connection to xxx.firebaseio.com/xxx was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: firebase

I've developed a few Web apps over the last year and have noticed the following console error on many occasions:

> The connection to
>   wss://s-usc1c-nss-222.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=[my-app-id] was
>   interrupted while the page was loading. *WebSocketConnection.js:122*

Sometimes this affects the saving of data, other times it doesn't seem to affect performance. I have not been able to detect a pattern.

This happens much more frequently during localhost testing but it also occurs on the live site.

The error displays more often on FF but I have seen it occur on Chrome as well. Oftentimes, if I leave the app for a while, I will see 10-20 of these errors in the console. No other errors are listed.

I have not seen this error reported anywhere else and so I'm having trouble diagnosing it, or even figuring out where to start.

**My setup:**

- Firebase version 4.8.1 (but have seen the error on previous versions throughout the past year)
- Blaze plan
- Web app using: Jquery 3.1.0 / JS / HTML5 / CSS3
- Firebase Email auth
- Firebase Realtime Database
- no other Firebase features
- Hosted on https via GoDaddy

Been struggling with this for a year. I'd really appreciate some help with this. Cheers!

Comment: Cross-posted on [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/dYQtzsl_lXQ), where it might have a better chance of getting answered.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about firebase-talk!

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when the page is unloaded before Firebase Realtime Database finishes establishing a connection to the server. The browser disconnects web sockets when closing down a page instance.

It's benign and not harmful to your data, but often is a symptom of other app problems.

Some common causes: 
  * Not catching your form submission events and preventing them from reloading the page.
  * Redirects on a page where Firebase is initialized (i.e. page starts to load, initializes Firebase, then redirects to a new page).
  * Using Firebase within iframes.

Hard to make a more firm diagnosis which case you're running into without a proper repro, but you should be able to sort that part. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran two instances of my app on different browsers and noticed that (for the most part) the disconnects occurred at the exact same time - to the second. Could this also be caused by my Internet connection dropping on/off?